Ошибка с CORS policy
Я просто шокирован, пишу сервер на spring boot
я в УКАЗАЛ ТО ЧТО ЛОКАЛХОТСУ 3000 МОЖНО ОТПРВЛЯТЬ ЗАПРОСЫ
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/v1/watch/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                        .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())
                        .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);
            }
        };
    }
}

но с фронта значит выскакивает ошибка cors при попытки получения видео номер 2 (с видео номер 1 ПОЧЕМУТО ВСЕ НОРМ, ХОТЯ И ТО И ТО ХРАНИТЬСЯ В ОДНОЙ ПАПКЕ)
я в папке static/api/v1/watch видео храню
при этом в postman все работет. фронт на next.js
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/watch/${episodeId}.mp4`, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                })

И еще, когда я отрубаю jwt настройки то все чудесным образом работает
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}

Я не знаю что мне делать, я вообще не понимаю в чем дело то. чат гпт тоже тупой

добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки, заголовки request и response. При запросе видео 1 и видео 2 есть различие в заголовках?
